# A to-infinitive preceded by a noun

Tags: grammar

I have learnt two points about "to-infinitive" as follows.

**verb + to + infinitive**

Its meaning is similar to "in order to" or "so as to".

- I come to pick you up.
- She runs to catch the bus.

**adjective + to + infinitive**

- It is hard to learn many languages simultaneously.
- This book is difficult to comprehend.

## Question

Does the structure "noun+to+infinitive" exist in English grammer? For example:

- I lend a screwdriver to open your watch.
- I am the math teacher to substitute for Mr. X who is absent today.

Bonus question: 
What is the difference (if any) between the following sentences?

A: This book is difficult to comprehend.

B: This book is difficult to be comprehended.

Comment: Sentence B is ungrammatical.

Comment: One of this site's rules is that a question here should focus on a single topic, so it's best not to ask "bonus questions".  You should ask about "difficult to be comprehended" in a separate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that pattern with a noun is grammatical.

> What's this?
>   -- It's a hat to put your beer in when you go to the football game.
>
> Here's a screwdriver to open your watch with.

The construction indicates "intended purpose".

Your teacher example is not right if your desired meaning is  "I am the substitute". Normally there'd be a participle clause there for that meaning, *...teacher substituting for ...*.

There's a *prospective* sense in this noun + infinitive construction:

> We're going to make a presentation to Acme Widgets next week.
>   -- Joe's *the man to take with you*. He knows their product line very well.

Joe is suitable for the intended purpose, namely, making a presentation to Acme Widgets.

So your sentence about the substitute teacher would be valid in a discussion about who would be a suitable substitute teacher for Mr. X; you would be suggesting that you are a person suited to that job:

> I don't know who we should send as the substitute teacher.
>   -- I'm just the math teacher to substitute for Mr. X, since I taught those students for most of last semester while Ms. J was out on maternity leave.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is used and your examples (especially the second one) is correct.

You should not think of the first example as a structure of its own ""noun + infinitive". It is a sentence with indirect object. The more clear way to express that would be something in the lines of: "I lent him a screwdriver to open..." for which the direct and indirect objects can switch places and a proposition would be necessary: "I lent a screwdriver to him to open..."

The bonus answer:
The two sentences imply the same meaning and concept, however, the second way is not so commonly used since it is a passive sentence for a situation when passive would not be necessary, because the omitted subject is not known.

keep on learning and good luck, 
Travis